# Adjusting iFrame size after page load

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have a reCaptcha in an iframe on my page. The reCaptcha changes it size, but the iframe not. This does not look nice. The users need to scroll now. I saw a few topics that address this problem. They work if the content stays the same during page load. But they do not work if the content changes when the page is loaded, this is happening in my case.

So my question is: how do I make an iFrame adjust size when the page is loaded using  **only html, css and if needed javascript** . This is my html code:

```
<div>
  <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="/partners/B2B_ReCaptcha"  frameborder="0" width="100%" 
  allowtransparency="true"  />
</div>
```

Any tips on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: I assume the iframe source is served over same domain, correct? You can access content of the iframe and calculate body height

Comment: Yes, it is served over the same domain, how would I calculate the body height?

Comment: I would post this as answer, but I don't have time to verify accuracy. Should be something like `const frame = `document.querySelector('iframe'); frame.width = frame.document.body.width` I think.

Comment: I am not succeeding in making it work. Could you maybe be more explicit?